# Break out out forloop but within switch statement php

Tags: php, switch-statement, break, for-loop

When I normally want to break out of a foreach loop before all of the iterations have completed I simply use a break; statement. e.g.

```
foreach($nodelist as $node) {
   if($metCriteria) {
       break;
   }
}
```

But my next example has a switch statement in it. And if one of the conditions are met then I need to break from the foreach loop. (The problem being the break is used for the switch statement)

```
foreach($nodelist as $node)
{
    switch($node->nodeName) {
        case "a" :
            //do something
            break;
        case "b" :
            //break out of forloop
            break;
    }
}
```

**Do I simply set a variable in the switch statement then break after it? e.g.**

```
$breakout = false;
foreach($nodelist as $node)
{
    switch($node->nodeName) {
        case "a" :
            //do something
            break;
        case "b" :
            $breakout = true;
            break;
    }
    if($breakout === true) break;
}
```

**Is this the best solution? or this there another way?**

Answer (score 74, accepted):

from the manual ([break](http://www.php.net/break))

> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

Comment: +1 This was exactly what I needed. Bonus points for using a built in language construct - I was doing it @Lizard style up until now.

Comment: 5.4.0 Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; break $num;) as the numerical argument.

Answer (score 20):

> The accepted Answer has no practical example let me share with you.

```
break 2
```

means exit from both loop and switch.

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

break 2;

break x will break out of that many levels

Answer (score -2):

Just use the {'s - it will keep the code from "running". Much better than the break-statement if you ask me.